# The narrow class group of an order of a quadratic field and the genera of binary quadratic forms

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $\mathfrak{F}$ be the set of binary quadratic forms over $\mathbb{Z}$.
Let $F = ax^2 + bxy + cy^2 \in \mathfrak{F}$.
Let $\alpha = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
p & q \\
r & s \end{array} \right)$ be an element of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$.
We write $f^\alpha(x, y) = f(px + qy, rx + sy)$.
Since $(f^\alpha)^\beta$ = $f^{\alpha\beta}$, $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ acts on $\mathfrak{F}$.

We say $D = b^2 - 4ac$ is the discriminant of $F$.
It is easy to see that $D \equiv 0$ (mod $4$) or $D \equiv 1$ (mod $4$).
If $D$ is not a square integer and gcd($a, b, c) = 1$, we say $ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$ is primitive.
If $D < 0$ and $a > 0$, we say $ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$ is positive definite.

Let $D$ be a non-square integer such that $D \equiv 0$ (mod $4$) or $D \equiv 1$ (mod $4$).
We denote the set of primitive binary quadratic forms of discriminant $D$ by $\mathfrak{F}_0(D)$.
We denote the set of primitive positive definite binary quadratic forms of discriminant $D$ by $\mathfrak{F}^+_0(D)$.
It is easy to see that $\mathfrak{F}_0(D)$, $\mathfrak{F}^+_0(D)$ are $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$-invariant.

If $D < 0$, we denote the set of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$-orbits on $\mathfrak{F}^+_0(D)$ by $C(D)$.

If $D > 0$, we denote the set of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$-orbits on $\mathfrak{F}_0(D)$ by $C(D)$.

Let $F \in \mathfrak{F}^+_0(D)$ if $D < 0$, $F \in \mathfrak{F}_0(D)$ if $D > 0$.
We denote by $[F]$ the $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$-orbit represented by $F$.

Let $\Phi_1,\dots,\Phi_{\mu}$ be the system of genus characters of discriminant $D$[see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191344/the-system-of-genus-characters-determined-by-a-binary-quadratic-form)].

We defined a homomorphism $\Phi\colon(\mathbb{Z}/D\mathbb{Z})^\times \rightarrow (\mathbb{Z}^\times)^\mu$ by $\Phi([n]) = (\Phi_1(n),\dots,\Phi_{\mu}(n))$ in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191415/the-homomorphism-defined-by-the-system-of-genus-characters).

Let $F \in \mathfrak{F}^+_0(D)$ if $D < 0$, $F \in \mathfrak{F}_0(D)$ if $D > 0$.
Let $m$ be an integer which is represented by $F$ and gcd($m, D) = 1$.
Then, by the proposition of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191344/the-system-of-genus-characters-determined-by-a-binary-quadratic-form), $\Phi_1([m]),\dots,\Phi_{\mu}([m])$ do not depend on the choice of $m$.
Since the set of integers represented by $F$ is determined by the class $[F]$, each $\Phi_i$ defines a map $C(D) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^\times$.
By abuse of notation, we denote this map by $\Phi_i$.
We write, by abuse of notation, $\Phi([F]) = (\Phi_1([F]),\dots,\Phi_{\mu}([F]))$.
Hence we get a map $\Phi\colon C(D) \rightarrow (\mathbb{Z}^\times)^\mu$.
We can define an equivalence relation on $C(D)$ by $\Phi([F]) = \Phi([G])$.
Each equivalence class of this relation is called a genus(Gauss: Disquisitiones Arithmeticae, art.231).
The genus which is represented by the prinicipal form is called the prinicipal genus(for the definition of the principal form, please see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191415/the-homomorphism-defined-by-the-system-of-genus-characters)) of discriminant $D$.
We would like to investigate the set of genera.

Let $S = \{ [m] \in (\mathbb{Z}/D\mathbb{Z})^\times; m$ is represented by $F\}$.
$S$ is determined by $[F]$.

Let $H = \{ [m] \in (\mathbb{Z}/D\mathbb{Z})^\times$; $m$ is represented by the principal form of discriminant $D\}$.

By the proposition of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192593/relation-between-a-primitive-binary-quadratic-form-of-discriminant-d-and-a-cer), $S$ is a residue class of Ker$(\chi)/H$,
where $\chi\colon (\mathbb{Z}/D\mathbb{Z})^\times\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^\times = \{-1, 1\}$ is the homomorphism defined in the proposition 2 of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191687/discriminant-of-a-binary-quadratic-form-and-jacobi-symbol).

Hence we get a map $\Psi\colon C(D) \rightarrow$ Ker$(\chi)/H$.
Since Ker$(\Phi) = H$ by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191415/the-homomorphism-defined-by-the-system-of-genus-characters), $\Psi([F]) = \Psi([G])$ if and only if $[F]$ and $[G]$ belong to the same genus.

On the other hand, by the proposition of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191830/discriminant-of-a-binary-quadratic-form-and-an-order-of-a-quadratic-number-field), there exists an order $R$ of a quadratic number field $K$ such that the discriminant of $R$ is $D$.
And there exists a bijection
$\psi\colon Cl^+(R) \rightarrow C(D)$ by the proposition of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192217/bijection-between-an-ideal-class-group-and-a-set-of-classes-of-binary-quadratic).
If we identify $C(D)$ with $Cl^+(R)$ by $\psi$, we get a map $\Psi\colon Cl^+(R) \rightarrow$ Ker$(\chi)/H$.

**My question**
Is the following proposition true?
If yes, how do we prove it?

**Proposition**
The map $\Psi\colon Cl^+(R) \rightarrow$ Ker$(\chi)/H$ is a homomorphism.