# The inverse class of the class represented by a primitive binary quadratic form of discriminant $D$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, quadratic-forms

We use the definitions of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192819/the-narrow-class-group-of-an-order-of-a-quadratic-field-and-the-genera-of-binary).

Is the following proposition true?
If yes, how do we prove it?

**Proposition**
Let $D$ be a non-square integer such that $D \equiv 0$ (mod $4$) or $D \equiv 1$ (mod $4$).
There exists a bijection
$\psi\colon Cl^+(R) \rightarrow C(D)$ by the proposition of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192217/bijection-between-an-ideal-class-group-and-a-set-of-classes-of-binary-quadratic).
We identify $C(D)$ with $Cl^+(R)$ by $\psi$.
Hence $C(D)$ is an abelian group with this identification.
Let $[F]$ be a class of $C(D)$ represented by a primitive form $F = ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$.
Let $G = ax^2 - bxy + cy^2$.
Then $[F][G] = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_1,\cdots, x_n$ be a sequence of elements of $R$.
We denote by $[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ the $\mathbb{Z}$-submodule of $R$ generated by $x_1,\cdots, x_n$.

Let $I = [a, (-b + \sqrt D)/2]$.
Let $J = [a, (-b + \sqrt D)/2]$.
$I$ and $J$ are primitive ideals of $R$.

$IJ = [a, (-b + \sqrt D)/2][a, (b + \sqrt D)/2]
= [a^2, a(b + \sqrt D)/2, a(-b + \sqrt D)/2, (D - b^2)/4]
= [a^2, ab, a(b + \sqrt D)/2, a(-b + \sqrt D)/2, ac]
= a[a, b, (b + \sqrt D)/2, (-b + \sqrt D)/2, c]
= aR$

This proves the assertion.