# Value at -1 of a certain Dirichlet character defined by Jacobi symbol

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $D$ be a non-square integer such that $D \equiv 0$ (mod $4$) or $D \equiv 1$ (mod $4$).
Let $\chi\colon (\mathbb{Z}/D\mathbb{Z})^\times\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^\times = \{-1, 1\}$ be the map defined in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/539968/a-condition-for-an-odd-prime-to-be-represented-by-a-binary-quadratic-form-of-a-g).
Let $n$ be an integer. We denote by $[n]$, the image of $n$ by the canonical map $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/D\mathbb{Z}$.
Computing values of $\chi$ at $[-1]$ for several $D$s, it seems that $\chi([-1]) = 1$ if $D \gt 0$ and $\chi([-1]) = -1$ if $D \lt 0$.

Is this true? If yes, how can we prove it?

Comment: I would like to point out the following policy of StackExchange because it doesn't seem to be well-known and some users seem to dislike a question to which the poster already knows the answer.
`[It’s also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question, as long as you pretend you’re on Jeopardy! — phrase it in the form of a question.
To be crystal clear, it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged.]`
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 1):

We will freely use the properties of the Jacobi symbol as stated in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/539006/proofs-of-the-properties-of-jacobi-symbol)
In particular, we have the folowing:

If $m \equiv 1$ (mod $4$), $\left(\frac{m}{n}\right) = \left(\frac{n}{m}\right)$.

If $m \equiv 3$ (mod $4$) and $n \equiv 3$ (mod $4$), $\left(\frac{m}{n}\right) = -\left(\frac{n}{m}\right)$.

If $m \equiv 1$ (mod $4$), $\left(\frac{-1}{m}\right) = 1$.

If $m \equiv 3$ (mod $4$), $\left(\frac{-1}{m}\right) = -1$.

**Case 1** $D \gt 0$ and $D \equiv 0$ (mod $4$)

$\chi([-1]) = \chi([D - 1]) = \left(\frac{D}{D-1}\right) = \left(\frac{D-1 +1 }{D-1}\right)
= \left(\frac{1}{D-1}\right) = 1$

**Case 2** $D \gt 0$ and $D \equiv 1$ (mod $4$)

$\chi([-1]) = \chi([2D - 1]) = \left(\frac{D}{2D-1}\right) = \left(\frac{2D-1}{D}\right)
= \left(\frac{-1}{D}\right) = 1$

**Case 3** $D \lt 0$ and $D \equiv 0$ (mod $4$)

We first note that $-D - 1 \equiv -1$ (mod $4$).

$\chi([-1]) = \chi([-D - 1]) = \left(\frac{D}{-D-1}\right) = \left(\frac{-(-D-1) -1 }{-D-1}\right)
= \left(\frac{-1}{-D-1}\right) = -1$

**Case 4** $D \lt 0$ and $D \equiv 1$ (mod $4$)

We first note that $-2D -1 \equiv 1$ (mod $4$).

$\chi([-1]) = \chi([-2D - 1]) = \left(\frac{D}{-2D-1}\right) = \left(\frac{-1}{-2D-1}\right)\left(\frac{-D}{-2D-1}\right) = \left(\frac{-2D - 1}{-D}\right) = \left(\frac{-1}{-D}\right) = -1$.