# Relation between an integer represented by a binary quadratic form and a certain Dirichlet character defined by Jacobi symbol

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-forms

Let $f = ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$ be a binary quadratic form over $\mathbb{Z}$.
We say $D = b^2 - 4ac$ is the discriminant of $f$.
It's easy to see that $D \equiv 0$ (mod $4$) or $D \equiv 1$ (mod $4$).
If $D$ is not a square integer and gcd($a, b, c) = 1$, we say $f$ is primitive.
If $D < 0$ and $a > 0$, we say $f$ is positive definite.
Let $m$ be an integer.
If $m = ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$ has a solution in $\mathbb{Z}^2$, we say $m$ is represented by $f$.

Is the following proposition true? If yes, how can we prove it?

**Proposition**
Let $D$ be a non-square integer such that $D \equiv 0$ (mod $4$) or $D \equiv 1$ (mod $4$).
Let $\chi\colon (\mathbb{Z}/D\mathbb{Z})^\times\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^\times = \{-1, 1\}$ be the map defined in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/539968/a-condition-for-an-odd-prime-to-be-represented-by-a-binary-quadratic-form-of-a-g).
Let $f$ be a primitive binary quadratic form $f$ of discriminant $D$.
If $D < 0$, we suppose that $f$ is positive definite.
Suppose $m$ is an integer which is relatively prime to $D$ and it is represented by $f$.
Then $\chi([m]) = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

In the following proof, we use freely the properties of the Jacobi symbol as stated in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/539006/proofs-of-the-properties-of-jacobi-symbol).

Suppose $f = ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$.
There exist integers $p, q$ such that $m = ap^2 + bpq + cq^2$.
Let $d =$ gcd$(p, q)$.
Let $p = dp'$, $q = dq'$.
Then $m = d^2(ap'^2 + bp'q' + cq'^2)$.
Let $n = ap'^2 + bp'q' + cq'^2$.
Since gcd$(p', q') = 1$, $n$ is properly represented by $f$.
Since $\chi([m]) = \chi([d])^2 \chi([n]) = \chi([n])$, we may assume $m$ is properly represented by $f$.

By this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191198/quadratic-residues-and-representations-of-integers-by-a-binary-quadratic-form), theres exists an integer $b$ such that $D \equiv b^2$ (mod $4m$).

**Case 1** $D \equiv 0$ (mod $4$) and $m \gt 0$

Since $m$ is odd, $\chi([m]) = \left(\frac{D}{m}\right) = \left(\frac{b^2}{m}\right) = \left(\frac{b}{m}\right)^2 = 1$.

**Case 2** $D \equiv 0$ (mod $4$) and $m \lt 0$

If $D \lt 0$, $f$ is positive definite by the assumption.
Hence $m \gt 0$ by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548433/conditions-for-a-real-binary-quadratic-form-to-be-positive-definite).
This is a contradiction.
Hence $D \gt 0$.
Since $m$ is relatively prime to $D$, $m$ is odd.
Since $D \equiv b^2$ (mod $4m$), $D \equiv b^2$ (mod $-m$).
Hence $\chi([-m]) = \left(\frac{D}{-m}\right) = \left(\frac{b^2}{-m}\right) = \left(\frac{b}{-m}\right)^2 = 1$.
Since $D \gt 0$, $\chi([-1]) = 1$ by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540697/value-at-1-of-a-certain-dirichlet-character-defined-by-jacobi-symbol).
Hence $\chi([m]) = \chi([-1])\chi([-m]) = \chi([-1]) = 1$.

**Case 3** $D \equiv 1$ (mod $4$) and $m \gt 0$

If $m$ is odd, $\chi([m]) = \left(\frac{D}{m}\right) = \left(\frac{b^2}{m}\right) = \left(\frac{b}{m}\right)^2 = 1$.
Hence we suppose $m$ is even.
Then we have $m = 2^\alpha n, \alpha \ge 1, n \ge 1$, where $n$ is odd.
Since $D \equiv b^2$ (mod $n$), $\chi([n]) = \left(\frac{D}{n}\right) = \left(\frac{b^2}{n}\right) = \left(\frac{b}{n}\right)^2 = 1$.
Hence $\chi([m]) = \chi([2^\alpha])\chi([n]) = \chi([2^\alpha])$.

If $\alpha$ is even, $\chi([2^\alpha]) = 1$.
Hence $\chi([m]) = 1$.

If $\alpha$ is odd, $\chi([2^\alpha]) = \chi([2])$.
Since $D \equiv b^2$ (mod $4m$), $D \equiv b^2$ (mod $8$).
Hence $D \equiv 1$ (mod $8$)
Hence $\chi([2]) = 1$ by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540754/value-at-2-of-a-certain-dirichlet-character-defined-by-jacobi-symbol).
Hence $\chi([m]) = 1$.

**Case 4** $D \equiv 1$ (mod $4$) and $m \lt 0$

If $D \lt 0$, $f$ is positive definite by the assumption.
Hence $m \gt 0$ by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548433/conditions-for-a-real-binary-quadratic-form-to-be-positive-definite).
This is a contradiction.
Hence $D \gt 0$.

Suppose $m$ is odd.
Since $D \equiv b^2$ (mod $4m$), $D \equiv b^2$ (mod $-m$).
Hence $\chi([-m]) = \left(\frac{D}{-m}\right) = \left(\frac{b^2}{-m}\right) = \left(\frac{b}{-m}\right)^2 = 1$.
Since $D \gt 0$, $\chi([-1]) = 1$ by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540697/value-at-1-of-a-certain-dirichlet-character-defined-by-jacobi-symbol).
Hence $\chi([m]) = \chi([-1])\chi([-m]) = 1$.

Suppose $m$ is even.
Then we have $m = -2^\alpha n, \alpha \ge 1, n \ge 1$, where $n$ is odd.
Since $D \equiv b^2$ (mod $n$), $\chi([n]) = \left(\frac{D}{n}\right) = \left(\frac{b^2}{n}\right) = \left(\frac{b}{n}\right)^2 = 1$.
Hence $\chi([m]) = \chi([-1])\chi([2^\alpha])\chi([n]) = \chi([-1])\chi([2^\alpha]) = \chi([2^\alpha])$.

If $\alpha$ is even, $\chi([2^\alpha]) = 1$.
Hence $\chi([m]) = 1$.

If $\alpha$ is odd, $\chi([2^\alpha]) = \chi([2])$.
Since $D \equiv b^2$ (mod $4m$), $D \equiv b^2$ (mod $8$).
Hence $D \equiv 1$ (mod $8$)
Hence $\chi([2]) = 1$ by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540754/value-at-2-of-a-certain-dirichlet-character-defined-by-jacobi-symbol).
Hence $\chi([m]) = 1$.
This completes the proof.