# Help proving Jacobi Symbol property $\left(\frac{-1}{n}\right) = (-1)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}$

Tags: number-theory, legendre-symbol, jacobi-symbol

Using the properties of Legendre symbols, I need to show $\left(\frac{-1}{n}\right) = (-1)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}$

Here is what I have so far

$\left(\frac{-1}{n}\right) = \left(\frac{-1}{p_1}\right)\left(\frac{-1}{p_2}\right) \cdots \left(\frac{-1}{p_k}\right)$ Where $p_1p_2\cdots p_k$ is the prime factorization of $n$. via the definition of Jacobi Symbols.

From the properties of Legendre symbols this is

$(-1)^{\frac{p_1 - 1}{2}}(-1)^{\frac{p_2 -1 }{2}} \cdots (-1)^{\frac{p_k-2}{2}} = (-1)^{\frac{p_1-1}{2}+\frac{p_2-1}{2}+\cdots + \frac{p_k-1}{2}}$

If I can show that $\frac{n-1}{2} \equiv \frac{p_1-1}{2}+\frac{p_2-1}{2}+\cdots + \frac{p_k-1}{2} \pmod{2}$. Then I would be there (I think).

I've been struggling with this for about an hour, and then decided to search. I found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/539006/proofs-of-the-properties-of-jacobi-symbol). However I don't understand the Lemma the answerer used in his proof.

> **Lemma 1**
>
> Let $a, b$ be odd integers.
>
> Then $(ab - 1)/2 \equiv (a - 1)/2 + (b - 1)/2$ (mod $2$).
>
> Proof:
>
> Since $a - 1$ and $b - 1$ are even,
>
> $(a - 1)(b - 1) \equiv 0$ (mod $4$).
>
> Hence $ab - a - b + 1 \equiv 0$ (mod $4$).
>
> Hence $ab - 1 \equiv (a - 1) + (b - 1)$ (mod $4$).
>
> Hence $(ab - 1)/2 \equiv (a - 1)/2 + (b - 1)/2$ (mod $2$).

Specifically how we go from this (which I understand)

> Hence $ab - a - b + 1 \equiv 0$ (mod $4$).

To this

> Hence $ab - 1 \equiv (a - 1) + (b - 1)$ (mod $4$).

Which I'm sure really obvious, but I just cant see it :(

If I understood that, can I then just use it to finish off the proof by stating that

$\frac{p_1-1}{2}+\frac{p_2-1}{2}+\cdots + \frac{p_k-1}{2} \equiv \frac{n-1}{2}\pmod{2}$ via lemma above, and so it follows that

$\left(\frac{-1}{n}\right) = (-1)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}$

Thanks for any help or insight

Comment: In $\left(\frac{-1}{n}\right) = (-1)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}$ the LHS is completely multipliccative by definition. Show the RHS is completely multiplicative too, thus it suffices to look at $n$ prime.

Comment: @reuns I'm not sure I follow....show $(n-1) = ( (p_1p_2\cdots p_k) -1)$?

Comment: For $n$ odd let $f(n) = \left(\frac{-1}{n}\right)$ and $g(n) = (-1)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}$, for $n$ even set $f(n) = g(n)=0$.  By definition $f(n)  = \prod_{p^k \| n} f(p)^k$. And it is clear that $g(mn) = g(m)g(n)$  so $g(n) = \prod_{p^k \| n} g(p)^k$. Thus it suffices to check that $f(p) = g(p)$.

Answer (score 2):

You are making hard work of this. The point is to prove that
$$\left(\frac{-1}n\right)=\chi(n)\tag1$$
where
$$\chi(n)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }n\equiv1\pmod 4,\\
-1&\text{if }n\equiv-1\pmod 4\end{cases}$$
for odd $n$. Now $\chi(mn)=\chi(m)\chi(n)$ and
also $\left(\frac{-1}{mn}\right)=\left(\frac{-1}m\right)
\left(\frac{-1}n\right)$. So if ($1$) holds for $m$ and $n$
it holds for $mn$, and it holds for all odd primes....

Comment: that makes sense, and I think I understand it, but if I don't explicitly tie $\frac{n-1}{2}$ into it, I wont get any credit.  or is that obvious in there and I just dont see that either, lol. Thanks for your help

Comment: $\chi(n)$ **is** $(-1)^{(n-1)/2}$