# A condition for an odd prime to be represented by a binary quadratic form of a given discriminant

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-forms, quadratic-reciprocity

Let $f = ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$ be an integral binary quadratic form.
We say $D = b^2 - 4ac$ is the discriminant of $f$.
If $D < 0$ and $a > 0$, we say $f$ is positive definite.
It is easy to see that $D \equiv 0$ (mod $4$) or $D \equiv 1$ (mod $4$).
If $D$ is not a square integer and gcd($a, b, c) = 1$, we say $ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$ is primitive.
Let $m$ be an integer.
If $m = ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$ has a solution in $\mathbb{Z}^2$, we say $m$ is represented by $f$.
If $m = ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$ has a solution $(s, t)$ such that gcd$(s, t) = 1$,
we say $m$ is properly represented by $f$.

Let $D$ be a non-square integer such that $D \equiv 0$ (mod $4$) or $D \equiv 1$ (mod $4$).
Let $n$ be an integer. We denote by $[n]$, the image of $n$ by the canonical map $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/D\mathbb{Z}$.
We claim that every element $(\mathbb{Z}/D\mathbb{Z})^\times$ is of the form $[m]$,
where $m$ is a positive odd integer.

If $D \equiv 0$ (mod $4$), this is clear.
So we assume $D \equiv 1$ (mod $4$).
Every element $(\mathbb{Z}/D\mathbb{Z})^\times$ is of the form $[a]$, where $a \gt 0$ and gcd$(a, D) = 1$.

If $a$ is odd, let $m = a$.

If $a$ is even, let $m = a + nD$, where $n$ is an odd integer such that $a + nD \gt 0$ and we are done.

We define a map $\chi\colon (\mathbb{Z}/D\mathbb{Z})^\times\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^\times = \{-1, 1\}$ as follows.

$\chi([m]) = \left(\frac{D}{m}\right)$, where $m$ is a positive odd integer which is relatively prime to $D$.

This is well defined by [the proposition of this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191687/discriminant-of-a-binary-quadratic-form-and-jacobi-symbol).
It is easy to see that $\chi$ is a group homomorphism.

Is the following proposition true?
If yes, how do we prove it?

**Proposition**
Let $D$ be a non-square integer such that $D \equiv 0$ (mod $4$) or $D \equiv 1$ (mod $4$).
Let $\chi\colon (\mathbb{Z}/D\mathbb{Z})^\times\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^\times = \{-1, 1\}$ be the map defined above.
Let $p$ be an odd prime number which does not divide $D$.
Then $\chi([p]) = 1$ if and only if $p$ is properly represented by a primitive form of discriminant $D$.
Moreover, if $D \lt 0$ and $\chi([p]) = 1$, $p$ is properly represented by a positive definite primitive form of discriminant $D$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\chi([p]) = 1$.
Then $\chi([p]) = \left(\frac{D}{p}\right) = 1$.
By my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/545508/a-condition-for-an-odd-integer-to-be-properly-represented-by-a-primitive-binary), $p$ is properly represented by a primitive form of discriminant $D$. Moreover, the proof of my answer shows that if $D \lt 0$, $p$ is properly represented by a positive definite primitive form of discriminant $D$.

Conversely suppose $p$ is properly represented by a primitive form of discriminant $D$.
By [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191198/quadratic-residues-and-representations-of-integers-by-a-binary-quadratic-form), $D$ is a quadratic residue modulo $4p$.
Hence $D$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$.
Hence $\chi([p]) = \left(\frac{D}{p}\right) = 1$.